# Retrieve the later date from a collection in Java

Tags: java, sql, collections

I was retrieving some date records from my database with the following results:

```
Date
09/18/2012 1:34:34 AM
09/8/2012 8:15:34 AM
09/8/2012 12:02:11 AM
08/30/2012 8:47:02 PM
08/29/2012 11:44:00 PM
```

As from the list above, there are 2 dates with **09/8/2012** that I would like to select  09/8/2012 8:15:34 AM (the later one), thus my result will look like this:

```
Date
09/18/2012 1:34:34 AM
09/8/2012 8:15:34 AM
08/30/2012 8:47:02 PM
08/29/2012 11:44:00 PM
```

How can I go about doing this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(date_column)
from table
group by trunc(date_column)
order by 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this don't work as well, cos like Collections.max it grabs the latest date from the collection.

Comment: This have nothing to do with java collections. Oracle will give you the desired dates.

Comment: Or I should say this doesn't work as well as sql's max() works like Collections framework's Collection.max().

Comment: Can't be. This query returns the second set, not the first. Returns one date per day, the latest.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min()` method from `Collections`

```
Collections.min(yourCollectionOfDate);
```

`java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` already implements comparator so you would get the late date by this method

If you want custom behavior then you can pass an instance of `Comparator` in `min()`

Also you could handle this at database side

Comment: Collections.max will retrieve the latest date of the list, so this does not work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it directly opn your query?

```
SELECT MAX(`DATE`) DateList
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DATE(`DATE`)
```

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool thanks for that. I overlooked 12:00am is later than 8:00am haha.. time to sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SortedSet to arrange all your Dates from low to high.
You could use either iterator() or descendingIterator() methods of TreeSet.
Here is an example

```
    TreeSet<Date> set = new TreeSet<Date>();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    set.add(df.parse("01.01.2000 12:00"));
    set.add(df.parse("01.01.2000 09:00"));
    set.add(df.parse("01.01.2000 18:00"));

    System.out.println("First date: " + set.first());
    System.out.println("Last date: " + set.last());

    System.out.println("From low to high:");
    for (Date date : set)
        System.out.println(date);

    System.out.println("From high to low:");
    Iterator<Date> backIterator = set.descendingIterator();
    while (backIterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(backIterator.next());
```